Using endfloat with appendices
I am not completely sure how to articulate this question, but:
I am working on a manuscript with figures that are discussed in the main text and should be included at the end of the main text, as well as figures that are briefly referred to in the main text but are relegated to an appendix.
The beauty of endfloat is that as long as I place a float close to the first place it is referred to in the text, it will appear in the correct order (at the end of the document) and the references in the text will be generated in the correct order (the first figure included will be "Figure 1", the second "Figure 2", etc.).
I would like to extend this to figures that are referred to in the main text but appear only in the appendix, and in the order it is referred to in the text ("Figure A1", etc.).
Here is an MWE, where I have to place the appendix figure into the appendix, rather than let endfloat do the work for me:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noheads,nolists,tablesfirst,nomarkers]{endfloat} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}



\section{Main Text}

Our first figure is Figure \ref{fig:first}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{First figure}
    \label{fig:first}
    FIRST FIGURE
\end{figure}

I would like for the next figure to go into the appendix and be called Figure A1. However, to do that, I have to manually put it after I call the appendix, like I've done here: Figure \ref{fig:appendix1}.


Our second figure in the main text is Figure \ref{fig:second}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Second figure}
    \label{fig:second}
    SECOND FIGURE
\end{figure}

\processdelayedfloats


\appendix 

\section{My Appendix}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{First appendix figure}
    \label{fig:appendix1}
    FIRST APPENDIX FIGURE
\end{figure}


\end{document}


And here is something like a minimal non-working example:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noheads,nolists,tablesfirst,nomarkers]{endfloat} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}



\section{Main Text}

Our first figure is Figure \ref{fig:first}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{First figure}
    \label{fig:first}
    FIRST FIGURE
\end{figure}

I would like for the next figure to go into the appendix and be called Figure A1. However, enfloat does not know that and just calls it Figure 2: Figure \ref{fig:appendix1}. 

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{First appendix figure}
    \label{fig:appendix1}
    FIRST APPENDIX FIGURE
\end{figure}

How can I tell endfloat that the above should go into the appendix? 

And now our second figure in the main text will be called Figure 3, like this: Figure \ref{fig:second}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Second figure}
    \label{fig:second}
    SECOND FIGURE
\end{figure}

\processdelayedfloats


\appendix 

\section{My Appendix}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}



\end{document}



welcome! possibly: use one of the packages available to create additional types of float and use a separate series for the ones which shouldn't go to the end. or, if you don't need tables as well, just misuse the table type and then use a package option to tell endfloat to ignore whichever type it should leave alone.

The manuscript also has tables, I just used figures in the MWE to keep things simple.

This creates a new float type appfigure which will be delayed, while normal figures and tables will not be delayed.  While this will fit multiple figures on each page, it still starts a new page for the Appendix.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noheads,nolists,nomarkers,nofigures,notables]{endfloat} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lof,
  listname=\listfigurename,
  name=\figurename,
  placement=htbp]{appfigure}
  
\renewcommand{\theappfigure}{A\arabic{appfigure}}
\DeclareDelayedFloat{appfigure}{\listfigurename}

\begin{document}

\section{Main Text}

Our first figure is Figure \ref{fig:first}.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{First figure}
    \label{fig:first}
    FIRST FIGURE
\end{figure}

I would like for the next figure to go into the appendix and be called Figure A1.

\begin{appfigure}
    \centering
    \caption{First appendix figure}
    \label{fig:appendix1}
    FIRST APPENDIX FIGURE
\end{appfigure}

And now our second figure in the main text like this: Figure \ref{fig:second}.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Second figure}
    \label{fig:second}
    SECOND FIGURE
\end{figure}

\appendix 
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\medskip}
\renewcommand{\efloatpreamble}{\section{My Appendix}}

\processdelayedfloats

\end{document}


This version puts all the floats, including the appendix, at the end.  I also figured out how to get rid of the initial \clearpage.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noheads,nolists,nomarkers,tablesfirst]{endfloat} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lof,
  listname=\listfigurename,
  name=\figurename,
  placement=htbp]{appfigure}
  
\renewcommand{\theappfigure}{A\arabic{appfigure}}
\DeclareDelayedFloat{appfigure}{\listfigurename}
\renewcommand{\efloatbegin}{\medskip\hrule}% no page break at start
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\hrule}% for multiple floats per page

\begin{document}

\section{Main Text}

Our first figure is Figure \ref{fig:first}.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{First figure}
    \label{fig:first}
    FIRST FIGURE
\end{figure}

I would like for the next figure to go into the appendix and be called Figure A1.

\addtodelayedfloat{appfigure}{\appendix\section{My Appendix}}% insert text

\begin{appfigure}
    \centering
    \caption{First appendix figure}
    \label{fig:appendix1}
    FIRST APPENDIX FIGURE
\end{appfigure}

And now our second figure in the main text like this: Figure \ref{fig:second}.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Second figure}
    \label{fig:second}
    SECOND FIGURE
\end{figure}

\processdelayedfloats

\end{document}


That works very well if I want the main text floats in-line. But ideally I would like to have the main text floats at the end of the main text, and then the appendix floats in the appendix.

You can only have one \processdelayedfloats, so they will all be together.  You can intermix text and delayed floats using \addtodelayedfloat in the ame order as the floats.

Yes, I guess what I was hoping for was something like \processdelayedmainfloats and \processdelayedappendixfloats.

These are great answers and do almost everything I would like to be able to do, esp. the 2nd one. The minor issue is that it locks the main text floats together with the appendix floats. In other words, you have main text floats followed immediately by the appendix floats. This is fine except that there may be a preference to have main text floats, some other appendix, and then the appendix floats. I guess you could handle this using the \addtodelayedfloat trick you mention but that could be awkward. Anyway, marking solved since this will probably work for 90% of users 90% of the time.
